# I want to remove a blurred Black Border from an image with openCv

Tags: python, opencv

[image: v]

I would like to remove the black borders from this image so that when I printed I do not run out of tonner.

I have tried the following procedure but it removes the whole image:

```
#Remove Black Borders from images
img = cv2.imread("images/myimage.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,10,256,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
crop = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('images/crop.png',crop)
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try getting mean of vertical and horizontal lines if means smaller than 100 change blacks to white:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("test.jpg",0).T #load image and transpose it(like rotate 90 degree)
sens=1.0 # (0-1]
meanofimg=np.mean(img)*sens #get avarage brightness of img
w,h=img.shape #get image's shape
for i in range(w): #for every horizontal line in transposed img(vertical line in normal)
    if np.mean(img[i])<meanofimg: #check if this line darker than avarage
        img[i]=(img[i]+255)%256 #add 255 for every pixel and get mod 256 this for make zeros 255 and do not touch others
        #img[i]=(img[i]*0+255) #for makin all pixels in line white
img=img.T #turn image to normal
for i in range(h): #every horizontal line in img
    if np.mean(img[i])<meanofimg: # if line darker than avarage
        img[i]=(img[i]+255)%256 #do same thing
        #img[i]=(img[i]*0+255) #for makin all pixels in line white

cv2.imwrite("output.jpg",img) #write img as output.jpg
```

for croping img:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("test.jpg",0).T
w,h=img.shape
sens=1.0 # (0-1]
meanofimg=np.mean(img)*sens
dataw=[w,0]
datah=[h,0]
for i in range(w):
    if np.mean(img[i])>meanofimg:
        if i<dataw[0]:
            dataw[0]=i
        else:
            dataw[1]=i
img=img.T
meanofimg=np.mean(img)*sens
for i in range(h):
    if np.mean(img[i])>meanofimg:
        if i<datah[0]:
            datah[0]=i
        else:
            datah[1]=i
img=img[datah[0]:datah[1],dataw[0]:dataw[1]]
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg",img)
```

Comment: Fantastic! What are you exctlay doing? Not sure I understand the procedure since it worked for this image but not for others.

Comment: @ruben you can change if np.mean(img[i])<100: for darker or brighter images if image darker decrase 100 to 50 or 25 or problem background still black change this line img[i]=(img[i]+255)%256 to this img[i]=(img[i]*0+255)

Comment: @ruben added some explanation for better understanding the algorithm